# ngCordova $watch function not working

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to make a function that runs when a toggle changed value.
But it won't run my watch function. Only the first time my apps open.

```
$scope.$watch('variable', function(){
   alert('waarde: '+$scope.variable);
});
```

And my html:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-toggle">
        {{variable}}
        <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="variable">
            <div class="track">
                <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It changes in the page it self but not in the controller.
How can I make it work?